# loading image from URL - How to capture the exception if the image is not there

Tags: delphi, http, exception, indy

My problem relates to the [other question I have asked about loading image from the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227646/how-to-get-images-from-url-in-delphi). 
The code below works.
However, I have encountered the problem if I try to get the image (it suppose be there) but
apparently was removed. The application does not know and returns the error. 
Is there a way to prevent it by capturing incoming error. 
I would appreciate any suggestions.
It happens at his line:

```
 IdHTTP1.get('http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif',MS);
```

Thanks, 
Chris

```
uses
  GIFImg;

 procedure TForm1.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
 var
   MS : TMemoryStream;
   GIf: TGIFImage;
 begin
     MS := TMemoryStream.Create;
    GIf := TGIFImage.Create;
   try
    IdHTTP1.get('http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif',MS);
    Ms.Seek(0,soFromBeginning);       
   Gif.LoadFromStream(MS);
   img1.Picture.Assign(GIF);

  finally
   FreeAndNil(GIF);
   FreeAndNil(MS);
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How do you capture the exception? The same way you capture any other exception. Use a `try`-`except` block.

```
procedure TForm1.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  MS : TMemoryStream;
  Gif: TGIFImage;
begin
  MS := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    Gif := TGIFImage.Create;
    try
      try
        IdHTTP1.Get('http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif', MS);
      except
        on e: EIdHTTPProtocolException do begin
          if e.ErrorCode = 404 then begin
            // not found
            exit;
          end else begin
            // some other reason for failure
            raise;
          end;
        end;
      end;
      MS.Position := 0;
      Gif.LoadFromStream(MS);
      img1.Picture.Assign(Gif);
    finally
      Gif.Free;
    end;
  finally
    MS.Free;
  end;
end;
```

When Indy gets an unacceptable response, it raises an exception of type `EIdHTTPProtocolException`. It does not raise a different exception class for each possible failure reason, so check the `ErrorCode` property for the numeric response. Refer to the [HTTP spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html) for the meanings of the various response codes.

It looks like Indy can be configured to ignore certain response codes via the `AIgnoreReplies` argument to `TIdCustomHTTP.DoRequest` method, but I've traced that parameter back as far as I'm willing to go today, so if you want more information about that, either ask a new question or someone can edit this answer to replace this paragraph with something more complete.

In my example above, I have checked for 404 (not found) and exit. Make sure you don't use `MS` if `Get` raises an exception because it will have indeterminate contents, and probably not a valid GIF image. For any other server response, I re-raise the exception so the caller can handle it instead. You'll probably want to change that. Any exception that's not a descendant of `EIdHTTPProtocolException` will get re-raised automatically. Do not catch exceptions for errors that you don't know how to resolve.

Comment: Thank you Rob, 
I was not sure how to apply except and your example solved my problem. 
I really appreciate. 
Chris

Answer (score 0):

every try has a **catch**
it is there the place where you should treat your exceptions
probably creating a blank image with some text on it **Image Not Available**

Comment: Well, no, in Delphi it's spelled *except*, not *catch*, and not every `try` has one. Some of them, as shown in the question, have a `finally` instead.